# How can I get component's position by ref in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, position

I'm using React 15.3.1 for my app. So, I need to get `Component` x and y positions in it's parent. The child is rendered like this:

```
<Icon key={key} ref={(c) => this['icon' + key] = c}}/>;
```

And this is how I try to access `Icon` (which is basically a `div`) position:

```
let icon = this['icon' + this.state.currentIcon.id];
icon.getBoundingClientRect(); //Error: "getBoundingClientRect" is not a function
```

The child is correct, I can see it's `props` in the debugger. But I cannot see any properties like `getBoundingClientRect`, `left`, `top` or any other position attributes. What I need to do to get them?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your `ref` will refer to `Icon`, which I'm guessing is a React Component.  You need to resolve the actual React Element (DOM element) before the `getBoundingClientRect` method will be available.

You can do this through the [ReactDOM.findDOMNode()](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode) function.

```
let icon = this['icon' + this.state.currentIcon.id];
const domNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(icon);
domNode.getBoundingClientRect()
```